# Substring IndexOf in c#

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have a string that looks like this: `"texthere^D123456_02"`. But I want my result to be `D123456`.

this is what i do so far:

```
if (name.Contains("_"))
{
name = name.Substring(0, name.LastIndexOf('_'));
}
```

With this I remove at least the `_02`, however if I try the same way for `^` then I always get back `texthere`, even when I use `name.IndexOf("^")`

I also tried only to check for `^`, to get at least the result:`D123456_02` but still the same result.

I even tried to `name.Replace("^"` and then use the substring way I used before. But again the result stays the same.

`texthere` is not always the same length, so `.Remove()` is out of the question.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You could split on ^ character and only take the second part. But I think a better option would be to use Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When call `Substring` you should not start from *0*, but from *the index found*:

```
  String name = "texthere^D123456_02";

  int indexTo = name.LastIndexOf('_');

  if (indexTo < 0)
    indexTo = name.Length;

  int indexFrom = name.LastIndexOf('^', indexTo - 1);

  if (indexFrom >= 0)
    name = name.Substring(indexFrom + 1, indexTo - indexFrom - 1);
```

Comment: While more complex this is the only approach that doesn't create unnecessary and temporary strings

Answer (score 7):

```
string s = "texthere^D123456_02";
            string result= s.Substring(s.IndexOf("^") + 1);//Remove all before
            result = result.Remove(result.IndexOf("_"));//Remove all after
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `String.Split` method :

```
    var split1 = name.Split('^')[1];
    var yourText = split1.Split('_')[0];
```

Or you could use RegExp to achieve basically the same.

Answer (score 4):

Your easiest solution would be to split the string first, and then use your original solution for the second part.

```
string name = "texthere^D123456_02";
string secondPart = name.Split('^')[1]; // This will be D123456_02
```

Afterwards you can use the Substring as before.

Answer (score 4):

**With Regular Expression**

```
 string s = "texthere^D123456_02";
 Regex r1 = new Regex(@"\^(.*)_");
 MatchCollection mc = r1.Matches(s);
 Console.WriteLine("Result is " + mc[0].Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: are you sure about the answer?

Answer (score 4):

use regex.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\^(.*)_");
Match match = regex.Match(name);

if(match.Success)
{
    name= match.Groups[1].Value
}
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to what's already been suggested is to use regex:

```
string result = Regex.Match("texthere^D123456_02", @"\^(.*)_").Groups[1].Value; // D123456
```

Answer (score 3):

An easier way would be to use Split

```
string s = "texthere^D123456_02";

string[] a = s.Split('^', '_');

if (a.Length == 3) // correct
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you use the same code you posted, it's doing the right thing, you start to retrieve characters from the char 0 and stop when it finds "^", so what you will get is "texthere".

If you want only the value, then use this:

```
name = name.Substring(0, name.LastIndexOf('_')).Substring(name.IndexOf("^") + 1);
```

It will first remove whatever is after the "_" and whatever is before "^".

Answer (score 3):

Substring takes a position and a length, so you need to actually figure out where your caret position is and where the underscore is to calculate the length

```
var name = "texthere^D123456_02";

if(name.Contains('_'))
{
    var caretPos = name.IndexOf('^') + 1; // skip ahead
    var underscorePos = name.IndexOf('_');
    var length = underscorePos - caretPos;
    var substring = name.Substring(caretPos, length);
    Debug.Print(substring);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this and let me know how it goes

```
  string inputtext = "texthere^D123456_02";
  string pattern = @".+\^([A-Z]+[0-9]+)\_[0-9]+";

  string result = Regex.Match(inputtext, pattern).Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Groups[0] returns the whole match, it should be Groups[1]

Answer (score 2):

```
String name = "texthere^D123456_02"
    print name.split('_', '^')[1]
```

This splits your string at all occurrences of _ and ^ and returns the list of strings after the split. Since the string you need D123456 would be at the 1st index, (i.e. the 2nd position), I have printed out that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just wanting the "d123456" it's simple with just `String.Split()` there is no need for anything else. Just define the index you want afterwards. There are overloads on `Split()` for this very reason.

```
//...

var source = "texthere^D123456_02";
var result = source.Split(new char[] {'^', '_'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
Console.WriteLine(result);
//Outputs: "D123456"
```

Hope this helps.